# Class combination not applying new style

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, svelte

I have a svelte button that is defined as so:

```
    <span class="nav-button" on:click={e => setActive(e.target,"nav-button")}>
        ...
    </span>
```

When the **setActive()** function below is run to apply the .active class:

```js
    // Toggles the active status of an element
    function setActive(e, bubble?:string) {

        // Optionally bubbles to spesified parent element
        if(bubble) while(!e.classList.contains(bubble)) e = e.parentElement;

        (e.classList.contains("active"))? e.classList.remove("active"):e.classList.add("active");
    }
```

It adds the **.active** class, but it does not add the style.

**.nav-button** is defined in SCSS as:

```
    .nav-button {   
        box-shadow: -7px -7px 20px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
        -4px -4px 5px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
        7px 7px 20px 0px #0002,
        4px 4px 5px 0px #0001,
        inset 0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
        inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #0001,
        inset 0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
        inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #0001;

        transition:box-shadow 0.25s cubic-bezier(.79,.21,.06,.81);


        &.active {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            0px 0px 0px 0px #0001,
            0px 0px 0px 0px #0001,
            inset -7px -7px 20px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            inset -4px -4px 5px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            inset 7px 7px 20px 0px #0003,
            inset 4px 4px 5px 0px #0001 !important;
        }
    }
```

See [here](https://streamable.com/7w3sp7), for video example.

If anyone could lend me some help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you seen with the DOM inspector tool in your browser? Are the ".active" rules being overridden with some other rules?

Comment: They dont apply to the element; the class is added to the html but no css is changed.

Comment: Right, but the DOM inspector should tell you **why**.

Comment: It dosen't show up in the styles list of the DOM inspector. The .active class isn't being applied, despite being added to the html.

Comment: Well maybe verify that the SASS-generated CSS is correct.

Comment: See [here](https://streamable.com/7w3sp7), everything seems to have generated correctly.

Comment: try `:global(.nav-button){
....
....
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you need the `:global` is because the compiler sees that the `.active` class is not used anywhere in the markup and it will remove it, adding the `:global` modifier tells the compiler: this class is applied somewhere that you cannot see, pleas keep it.

Note that using the `:global` method will also remove the scope from your styling, meaning that if this class appears elsewhere in your project it will also applied there, this is the main reason this is really the last resort.

But for your case you don't need, you just have to embrace Svelte fully.

The first thing to remember is that when working with Svelte, it is generally a bad practice to do DOM manipulation in your JavaScript, instead you should rely on the state of your components to update themselves instead.

That said, you can scrap your `setActive` function and replace it with a singular variable:

```js
  let active
```

The goal is to simply place in *active* some kind of identification of the current element. We could simply do this by changing the `on:click`

```html
<span on:click={() => active = 1}>...</span>
<span on:click={() => active = 2}>...</span>
```

(change the number with whatever you would want, like a string or an id)

Finally use the *conditional classes* feature from Svelte

```html
<span class:active={active === 1}>...</span>
```

Using the notation: `class:xxx={condition}>` will add the class *xxx* to your element if *condition* evaluates to true.

So the total code would be:

```html
<script>
  let active
</script>

<span class:active={active === 1} class="nav_button" on:click={() => active = 1}>...</span>
<span class:active={active === 2} class="nav_button" on:click={() => active = 2}>...</span>
<span class:active={active === 3} class="nav_button" on:click={() => active = 3}>...</span>

<style>
 /* here your styles */
</style>
```

This way the class `active` is actually used in the markup and the compiler will not remove it for you, reducing the risk of applying the same rules elsewhere as the class will still be scoped to this component.

(Personally, I also thinks it makes the code easier to comprehend)

Answer (score 1):

A big thank you to @dagalti for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415716/class-combination-not-applying-new-style?noredirect=1#comment113903628_64415716)!

The **.nav-button** class must be changed to:

```
    :global(.nav-button) { 
        box-shadow: -7px -7px 20px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            -4px -4px 5px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            7px 7px 20px 0px #0002,
            4px 4px 5px 0px #0001,
            inset 0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #0001,
            inset 0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
            inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #0001;

            transition:box-shadow 0.25s cubic-bezier(.79,.21,.06,.81);


            &.active {
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
                0px 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
                0px 0px 0px 0px #0001,
                0px 0px 0px 0px #0001,
                inset -7px -7px 20px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
                inset -4px -4px 5px 0px var(--shadow-primary),
                inset 7px 7px 20px 0px #0003,
                inset 4px 4px 5px 0px #0001 !important;
            }
        }
```

You can see the working example [here](https://streamable.com/g6ktci?fbclid=IwAR125Y6KY8wm35_wWffSKioIaVpyND5WMiAmxeP7dx4l2jqmOISRHurPoFI).